# Creating polygons (squares) from point using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, plsql

[image]

I want to create a regular grid of polygons/squares from this point knowing that between two successive points 100 meters, so each square would have 100*100 m2 in its area.

Comment: SInce you have this tagged with PostgreSQL, I'm assuming you want to do this in SQL.  If you take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), you'll see that coding questions are expected to contain code.  Please **edit** this question to include at least the query which results in the points, then start working on the insert component (hint: corners are at +/- half the side offsets)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the coordinate system of your points uses meters, you can produce boxes centered around those points with [ST_Expand](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_Expand.html).  For example:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Expand('POINT (0 0)'::geometry, 4));

              st_astext               
--------------------------------------
 POLYGON((-4 -4,-4 4,4 4,4 -4,-4 -4))
```