# Make square polygon from one point and area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, polygon-creation

I have a shapefile of points with a variety of attributes, the relevant ones being "ID", "area", "lat", and "long". Such as...
[image]
The lat/long coordinates are always the SW corner of a plot and the area varies from 10 to 50 km-sq. Each plot is always a square. I would like to make a polygon shapefile from the point shapefile that displays the entire plot to be able to clip other features. To look similar to...
[image]
This is a one-time operation in this case and I would like to do it in Arc (I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2) but would be willing to use R if it is easier. Maybe it would be easiest to calculate the coordinates of each corner first? I have found answers similar to my question in:

- [Createing polygon layer from point data using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34992/create-a-polygon-layer-from-point-data),
- [Creating polygons (squares) from point using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188220/how-to-create-a-polygons-squares-from-point), and
- [Calculating coordinates of square x miles from center point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15545/working-out-the-coords-of-a-square-x-miles-from-a-center-point),

but not quite what I want and using different programs.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). This would be easy enough using Python, but programming questions here are expected to include code.  There are multiple reasons for this, but it comes down to allowing us to help you, not do it for you.

Comment: You have included both Arcgis and r tags? in which platform do you intend to implement this?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197650/adding-polygons-on-points-using-arcgis-10-2/197679#197679

Comment: Thanks for the tips and links. I was hoping I was just missing an Arc tool that I could use rather than write any code, hence the lack of code in the question, but I will try to modify @FelixIP posted.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up calculating the center point of each polygon from the SW point in the dataset by moving the point 45 degrees NE, 1.41 * side length, based on area given. Then I used the answer given in: [Creating square buffer around point feature using ArcGIS for Desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29337/creating-square-buffer-around-point-feature-using-arcgis-for-desktop). That worked great. Alternatively I am trying the Python code that is also linked in the answer.